# CDateTimeCtrl up down buttons reversed

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a CDateTimeCtrl object in my application that displays a time in HH:MM:SS and has an up down control using DTS_UPDOWN. But when I highlight one of the fields and press the up button, it decreases and when pushing down, it increases. why would this be?

Comment: Code? Screenshots? We can't read your mind dude.

Comment: What OS are you running on? The behavior you describe is the standard way up/down controls work, but on my Win7 machine DateTime fields with `DTS_UPDOWN` set do not exhibit this - clicking the up button increases the number. This makes me think Microsoft may have changed their behavior in DateTime fields at some point.

Comment: @Jonathan I am using windows 7

Comment: What behavior do you get in the system Date and Time control panel (Change date and time)?

Comment: That works as expected. Are there any event handlers for those buttons? Because through my own research I can't seem to find any. Or is simply declaring DTS_UPDOWN supposed to be it and Windows takes care of the rest?

Comment: Also, my application works as expected on XP

Comment: Did you call [SetRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcc548ca(v=vs.90).aspx)?